# Hibernate duplicate values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I'am studying Hibernate and faced with little problem.

I have a class Item, witch mapped on DB with same columns:

```
@Entity
class Item {
    private long id;
    private long hash;
    private String name;
    // ... constructors/getters/setters ...
}
```

Hashes(CRC, Adler, nevermind) generated on programm initialization. They can be duplicated for some reason.

Question is: how to get Map < Long, Item >, were key is hash?

Comment: Get the rows...Build the map yourself...

Comment: @DanglingPiyush It is not present any the automatic solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What for do you need hash column in this example?

1. Database Id is uniqe, you can use it like hash or generate hash from it
2. you should anotate id with identity @Id
3. you should override equals(), hash() functions correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hashes is used for determining identical items and collecting them in lists. Map is used for collecting this lists by hash. Also, all annotations added on a getters. About equals() and hash() methods - thaks, look at them.

Comment: Exactly you dont need to add hash property into your entity. For that reason there is Object.hash() funtion. For JPA entities it should by ovveriden usinf database ID.
Not all maps implementations are using hash. For sure HashMap does.

Comment: Look here: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=1